# ROS subscriber undefined reference

Tags: ros

I am trying to write a subscriber callback function, however i get the error undefined reference to callback.

Main

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "Lidar");
ros::NodeHandle n;
Lidar scan;

ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/scan", 1, &Lidar::scanCallback, &scan);
```

Header

```
//Lidar.hpp
class Lidar {
    public:
        float distance = 100;
       void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg);
};
```

Callback

```
//Lidar.cpp

    void Lidar::scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg) {

    Lidar::distance = msg->ranges[0];
    ROS_INFO("data %f",msg->ranges[0]);

}
```

Comment: Much more information is needed actually debug. What does your CMakeLists.txt look like?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, lidar.cpp wasnt included in the CMakeList